# What Unity Lenses and Scopes are available to add?

Tags: unity, 13.04, lenses, scopes

I am curious to know what sort of unity scopes can we add in Ubuntu 13.04.
I have tried a YouTube lens but it doesn't work.

Are there any scopes/lenses (except the default ones) I can add to the Unity Dash?

Comment: You get a lollipop! 100,000th question?

Comment: lol.hope I get the answers too.